# standard practice to place the ssl certificates

Tags: git, ssl, https

Currently I put the ssl certificates in the same repo that contains the https server code.

Although it seems wrong to do it this way but if I don't do this how do I manage load balancing / auto scaling in the future?

Is there a standard practice for doing this?

Comment: Does that include the private key used to build that ssl certificate?

Answer (score 2):

> Currently I put the ssl certificates in the same repo that contains the https server code.

As long as you don't store your **private** keys (which you generate/sign the certificate with) in the same repository there is no problem with that.

> Is there a standard practice for doing this?
> The answer will be opinined-based since there isn't such a rule or a based practice how to do it.

You need to keep in mind that you will need the certificate on every server so it makes sense to place it in the repo since its a public content, but if you also need the keys - that's another story.

They should be kept in a separate location (can be repo as well).

---

#### Where to store the keys used by the certificate?

Its up to you where would like to keep it as long as it in safe place.

Comment: but to start an https server you need they key, cert and bundle.ca as the input arguments. How do you not have key in the repo but is able to reference it when doing auto-scaling?